# After Software Update, all icons missing, cannot open terminal, settings, folder. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome

To open terminal i have to use Ctrl + Alt + F3. Application like google chrome or visual code still working but other native software like screenshot or software update window cannot open.

I have tried this and didn't work

`sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center`

Comment: Hello. What commands did you use that you think caused this. The title says you can not open terminal the question says you can?

Comment: On the tty (Ctrl+Alt+F3), try "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" and see if there are any errors. If not, your system is fine, and the issue may be with your account (have you run graphical applications with sudo?).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a text-only virtual console by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Reinstall the default Python 3 version by running the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-all
   ```
5. Switch out of the virtual console and return to your desktop environment by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

---

After you have installed the default Python 3 version, you need to get back your default Ubuntu desktop system. In order to avoid messing something up, do it in the following order:

1. First install the terminal from a virtual console using the command: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-terminal`. If you can't install gnome-terminal at all, skip this step and go to step 2.
2. Return to your desktop and open the terminal using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Run this command instead to reinstall the  default Software application and the default Settings application:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-software gnome-control-center
   ```

   If you still can't open the terminal, run the same command from a virtual console instead. If you can't install the default software application at all, skip this step and go to step 3.
3. Open the terminal and try to open the Ubuntu Software app from the terminal by running `gnome-software`. From the Ubuntu Software app install the Ubuntu desktop system or else open the terminal (or a virtual console) and install the Ubuntu desktop system by running the command: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`.